# Не работает кнопка выхода в проекте godot

Tags: godot, gdscript

Есть следующий код кнопки выхода:

```
func _on_Exit_pressed():
# warning-ignore:return_value_discarded
    $ClickSound.play()
    yield($ClickSound, "finished")
    get_tree().exit()
```

При нажатии кнопки окно закрывается, но сама игра продолжает работать и godot выдаёт ошибку: "Invalid call. Nonexistent function 'exit' in base 'SceneTree'.". При нажатии на крестик в углу окна закрывается правильно. Как можно исправить данную ошибку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему сам. Нужно вместо exit() написать quit().